# Asynchronous API call, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm working on an application I inherited that makes asynchronous calls to an API. The application sends about 60 asynchronous requests to the API, and then retrieves them as they are ready. The API returns the results in the form of a zip archive object. It was using the following (abbreviated) code to retrieve results from the API, but this kept throwing intermittent System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException errors

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
Stream responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
responseStream.Seek(0, 0);
za = new ZipArchive(responseStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
```

So I attempted to fix this by using await, and implemented the following methods, but I'm still getting the same errors. I can check the status of my API requests through a website, so I know they're not being canceled by the API. The requests that fail, fail in less than 5 minutes, so I know it's also not because the timeout value is too low on the HTTPClient. This is my first crack at asynchronous programming so if anyone can help with this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    public async Task<ZipArchive> GetExport(SourceTable sourceTable)
    {
        ZipArchive zipArchive = null;

        switch (GetResultStatus(sourceTable))
        {
            case null:
                break;

            case "Completed":
                {
                    zipArchive = await RetrieveResult(sourceTable);
                }
                break;
        }
        return zipArchive;
    }

    private async Task<ZipArchive> RetrieveResult(SourceTable sourceTable)
    {
        Export export = sourceTable.exports[0];
        ZipArchive za = await RetrieveResultAsync(export);

        return za;
    }

    private async Task<ZipArchive> RetrieveResultAsync(Export export)
    {
        ZipArchive za = null;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.Timeout.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)); //5 minutes

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(restURL + "file/" + export.FileId);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        responseStream.Seek(0, 0);
        za = new ZipArchive(responseStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);

        return za;
    }
```

UPDATE: After adding some more logging to this code I found out that it was indeed a timeout issue, and that I wasn't setting the timeout value correctly. When setting the value like below, it resolved the issues (of course with setting a higher timeout value than the default)

```
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);                 
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(httpClientTimeout);
```

Comment: Intermittent failure seems like there might be a race condition going on somewhere, perhaps with the other tasks.

AFAIK (i'm happy to be corrected), task cancellations are usually the result of a cancellation token somewhere in the code, if you can find the logic referring to that it might give you some clues.

Comment: I searched the project and there's no reference to a cancellation token